# Create text file in swf that downloads to users computer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser

Is it possible to create a text file on the fly in swf/flash running in a users’ browser and prompt the user to download the file to his computer?

I am familiar with the FileReference class, but I cannot figure out a way for this class to work without reading the file to be downloaded from a server.

Edit: For this to fully work in my use case the swf/browser should handle the file more or less like a file downloaded from remote servers - meaning that it should prompt the user and ask what he would like to do with the file and give the option to open file in default application (or open automatically if that is what the user has set as the default action for such files).

Comment: Flash is extremely restrictive on file I/O when it's being run in the browser.  AIR's a good bit more lenient though.  Adobe tends to block you from doing hardly anything with it in through Flash Player for security reasons, but I don't know that there's not a work-around or exception to the rule here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
file.save("this is a text", "file.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. However it forces the file to be saved and does not offer the user to open the file in its standard application, probably due to safety concerns. Is it possible to not force saving but follow the the same rules that would apply if a file was directly download from a remote server?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, and it's not what you asked initially ;) you would have to save it to the server and use navigateToUrl

Comment: Yea I agree that I could have been more clear about the "prompt" part.